# Structr - Unable to connect to Neo4j

Tags: structr

"Connection to the database terminated. This can happen due to network instabilities, or due to restarts of the database." But my Neo4j DB is online and can be reached - Also in the shown logs there is not indication that the connection is the issue...

Neo4j
Version:    4.2.5
Edition:    community

Structr Version: 3.6.4

What did I miss? (Changed the default neo4j password and can create nodes in the Neo4j Browser)

[image]

Have a look on the Logfile output here:

Thank you some hints would be awesome :-)

```
2021-04-28 15:19:57.783 [qtp1136289998-21] INFO  org.structr.schema.SchemaService - Schema build took a total of 22513 ms

2021-04-28 15:19:57.784 [qtp1136289998-21] INFO  org.structr.core.graph.NodeService - Shutting down database service

2021-04-28 15:19:57.785 [qtp1136289998-21] INFO  org.structr.core.Services - Creating NodeService..

2021-04-28 15:21:14.882 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.Services - Creating NodeService..

2021-04-28 15:21:14.882 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.graph.NodeService - Database driver loaded, initializing indexes..

2021-04-28 15:21:14.882 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.graph.NodeService - Indexes successfully initialized.

2021-04-28 15:21:14.892 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.graph.NodeService - Database contains 0 nodes, 0 relationships.

2021-04-28 15:21:14.894 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.graph.NodeService - Creating initial user..

2021-04-28 15:21:14.902 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.Services - Creating NodeService..

2021-04-28 15:21:14.916 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.graph.NodeService - Database driver loaded, initializing indexes..

2021-04-28 15:21:14.917 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.graph.NodeService - Indexes successfully initialized.

2021-04-28 15:21:14.917 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.graph.NodeService - Database contains 0 nodes, 0 relationships.

2021-04-28 15:21:14.919 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.graph.NodeService - Creating initial user..

2021-04-28 15:21:22.002 [qtp1136289998-25] WARN  org.structr.schema.SchemaHelper - Unknown property ui in non-graph properties, ignoring.

2021-04-28 15:21:23.664 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  o.s.schema.compiler.NodeExtender - Compiling 264 dynamic entities...

2021-04-28 15:21:33.372 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  o.s.schema.compiler.NodeExtender - Compiling done in 9706 ms

2021-04-28 15:21:33.740 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  o.s.schema.compiler.NodeExtender - Successfully compiled 264 dynamic entities: A.java, Abbr.java, AbstractFile.java, AbstractMinifiedFile.java, Address.java, ApplicationConfigurationDataNode.java, Area.java, Article.java, Aside.java, Audio.java, B.java, Base.java, Bdi.java, Bdo.java, Blockquote.java, Body.java, Br.java, Button.java, Canvas.java, Caption.java, Cdata.java, Cite.java, Code.java, Col.java, Colgroup.java, Command.java, Comment.java, Component.java, ConceptGroup.java, ConceptGroupLabel.java, Content.java, ContentContainer.java, ContentItem.java, CssDeclaration.java, CssRule.java, CssSelector.java, CssSemanticClass.java, CustomConceptAttribute.java, CustomNote.java, CustomTermAttribute.java, DOMElement.java, DOMNode.java, DataFeed.java, Datalist.java, Dd.java, Definition.java, Del.java, Details.java, Dfn.java, Div.java, Dl.java, DocumentFragment.java, Dt.java, EMailMessage.java, EditorialNote.java, Em.java, Embed.java, Favoritable.java, FeedItem.java, FeedItemContent.java, FeedItemEnclosure.java, Fieldset.java, Figcaption.java, Figure.java, File.java, Folder.java, Footer.java, Form.java, G.java, Group.java, H1.java, H2.java, H3.java, H4.java, H5.java, H6.java, Head.java, Header.java, Hgroup.java, HistoryNote.java, Hr.java, Html.java, I.java, Iframe.java, Image.java, Img.java, Indexable.java, IndexedWord.java, Input.java, Ins.java, JavaScriptSource.java, KafkaClient.java, Kbd.java, Keygen.java, LDAPGroup.java, LDAPUser.java, Label.java, Legend.java, Li.java, Link.java, LinkSource.java, Linkable.java, Localization.java, Location.java, MQTTClient.java, MailTemplate.java, Mailbox.java, Main.java, Map.java, Mark.java, Menu.java, MessageClient.java, MessageSubscriber.java, Meta.java, MetadataNode.java, Meter.java, MinifiedCssFile.java, MinifiedJavaScriptFile.java, Nav.java, NodeLabel.java, Noscript.java, Note.java, ODFExporter.java, ODSExporter.java, ODTExporter.java, Object.java, Ol.java, Optgroup.java, Option.java, Output.java, P.java, Page.java, Param.java, PaymentItemNode.java, PaymentNode.java, Person.java, Pre.java, PreferredTerm.java, Principal.java, Progress.java, Q.java, RemoteDocument.java, Rp.java, Rt.java, Ruby.java, S.java, Samp.java, ScopeNote.java, Script.java, Section.java, Select.java, ShadowDocument.java, SimpleNonPreferredTerm.java, Site.java, Small.java, Source.java, Span.java, SplitNonPreferredTerm.java, Strong.java, StructuredDocument.java, StructuredTextNode.java, Style.java, Sub.java, Summary.java, Sup.java, Table.java, Tbody.java, Td.java, Template.java, Textarea.java, Tfoot.java, Th.java, Thead.java, Thesaurus.java, ThesaurusArray.java, ThesaurusConcept.java, ThesaurusTerm.java, Time.java, Title.java, Tr.java, Track.java, U.java, Ul.java, User.java, Var.java, VersionHistory.java, Video.java, VideoFile.java, VirtualProperty.java, VirtualType.java, Wbr.java, Widget.java, XMPPClient.java, XMPPRequest.java, AbstractFileCONTAINS_NEXT_SIBLINGAbstractFile.java, AbstractMinifiedFileMINIFICATIONFile.java, ConceptGrouphasAsMemberThesaurusConcept.java, ConceptGrouphasConceptGroupLabelConceptGroupLabel.java, ConceptGrouphasSubGroupConceptGroup.java, ContentContainerCONTAINSContentContainer.java, ContentContainerCONTAINSContentItem.java, CssRuleCONTAINSCssRule.java, CssRuleHAS_DECLARATIONCssDeclaration.java, CssRuleHAS_SELECTORCssSelector.java, CssSemanticClassMAPS_TOCssSelector.java, DOMElementRELOADSDOMElement.java, DOMNodeCONTAINSDOMNode.java, DOMNodeCONTAINS_NEXT_SIBLINGDOMNode.java, DOMNodePAGEPage.java, DOMNodeSYNCDOMNode.java, DataFeedHAS_FEED_ITEMSFeedItem.java, EMailMessageHAS_ATTACHMENTFile.java, FeedItemFEED_ITEM_CONTENTSFeedItemContent.java, FeedItemFEED_ITEM_ENCLOSURESFeedItemEnclosure.java, FolderCONTAINSAbstractFile.java, FolderCONTAINSFile.java, FolderCONTAINSFolder.java, FolderCONTAINSImage.java, GroupCONTAINSPrincipal.java, ImagePICTURE_OFUser.java, ImageTHUMBNAILImage.java, IndexableINDEXED_WORDIndexedWord.java, LinkSourceLINKLinkable.java, MailboxCONTAINS_EMAILMESSAGESEMailMessage.java, MessageClientHAS_SUBSCRIBERMessageSubscriber.java, NoterefersToThesaurusConcept.java, ODFExporterEXPORTS_TOFile.java, ODFExporterGETS_TRANSFORMATION_FROMVirtualType.java, ODFExporterUSES_TEMPLATEFile.java, PaymentNodepaymentItemPaymentItemNode.java, PrincipalFAVORITEFavoritable.java, SimpleNonPreferredTermUSEPreferredTerm.java, SiteCONTAINSPage.java, SplitNonPreferredTermUSEPreferredTerm.java, StructuredDocumentMETADATAMetadataNode.java, StructuredTextNodeCONTAINSStructuredTextNode.java, StructuredTextNodeNEXTStructuredTextNode.java, ThesaurusArrayhasMemberArrayThesaurusArray.java, ThesaurusArrayhasMemberConceptThesaurusConcept.java, ThesaurusArrayhasNodeLabelNodeLabel.java, ThesaurusConcepthasCustomConceptAttributeCustomConceptAttribute.java, ThesaurusConcepthasCustomNoteCustomNote.java, ThesaurusConcepthasHierRelConceptThesaurusConcept.java, ThesaurusConcepthasHistoryNoteHistoryNote.java, ThesaurusConcepthasNonPreferredLabelSimpleNonPreferredTerm.java, ThesaurusConcepthasPreferredLabelPreferredTerm.java, ThesaurusConcepthasRelatedConceptThesaurusConcept.java, ThesaurusConcepthasScopeNoteScopeNote.java, ThesaurusConcepthasSubordinateArrayThesaurusArray.java, ThesaurusConcepthasTopConceptThesaurusConcept.java, ThesaurusTermhasCustomTermAttributeCustomTermAttribute.java, ThesaurusTermhasDefinitonDefinition.java, ThesaurusTermhasEditorialNoteEditorialNote.java, ThesaurusTermhasHistoryNoteHistoryNote.java, ThesauruscontainsConceptGroup.java, ThesauruscontainsThesaurusArray.java, ThesauruscontainsThesaurusConcept.java, ThesaurushasVersionVersionHistory.java, UserHOME_DIRFolder.java, UserWORKING_DIRFolder.java, VideoFileHAS_CONVERTED_VIDEOVideoFile.java, VideoFileHAS_POSTER_IMAGEImage.java, VirtualTypevirtualPropertyVirtualProperty.java, XMPPClientPENDING_REQUESTXMPPRequest.java

2021-04-28 15:21:36.620 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.schema.SchemaService - Schema build took a total of 21699 ms

2021-04-28 15:21:36.623 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.graph.NodeService - Shutting down database service

2021-04-28 15:21:36.625 [qtp1136289998-25] INFO  org.structr.core.Services - Creating NodeService..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structr 3.6.4 is compatible with Neo4j 3.x.

Our current 4.0-SNAPSHOT builds support Neo4j 4.x.

As we are pretty close to a release of 4.0 and it contains many new features and fixes, I would recommend you use a SNAPSHOT version if you are not running on production yet.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need GraalVM instead of JDK for the 4.0-SNAPSHOT version. Here's an article on how to install/migrate to 4.x https://docs.structr.com/docs/structr-4x-migration-guide

Comment: yeah i just followed the hint in the logs: "Please set application.runtime.enforce.recommended = false in structr.conf to enable start despite Java Runtime Version mismatch." and i have it running :-) Thank you for your fast and helpful support!